# Change table row by index

Tags: abap

How can I give a field a value with a specific index. 
Or if the field is not initial I wanna change the value on this index
Example:

```
TYPES : BEGIN OF itab,
         number1 type n,
endof itab.

lv_tabix = sy-tabix.

itab-number1 index lv-tabix = '1'.
```

Comment: I don't understand what're trying to achieve ?  because `itab-number1 index lv-tabix = '1'.` is **Invalid**.  that too `itab` is types. First learn about difference between **TYPE** and **DATA**, also **Internal table** and **Structure**. [Internal tables](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenitab_guidl.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Just use [table expressions](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abentable_expressions.htm) for this, if you are on the recent ABAP releases:

```
TRY. 

    itab[ lv-tabix ]-number1  = '1'.

 CATCH cx_sy_itab_line_not_found INTO DATA(exc). 
 cl_demo_output=>display( exc->get_text( ) ). 
ENDTRY.
```

Comment: My preferred solution because it's a 1 liner that looks like an array in other languages, but needs careful selection of index or exception handling (much like an array).

Comment: I like it the most too, but I cannot use it because my system's version.
So, why not to merge all three answers in yours?

Comment: Let all answers lay, just for options.

Comment: @Zero, yep, valuable note about exceptions. Added the handling.

Answer (score 2):

You should read table by index and assign target line to filed symbol first:

```
READ TABLE {your itab} INDEX lv_tabix ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs>).
<fs>-number1 = '1'.
```

Depending on your server version, seperate field symbol declaration may be needed:

```
 FIELD-SYMBOLS <fs> TYPE {your table line type}
```

Check READ TABLE online help https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapread_table_outdesc.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_2@2@

Answer (score 2):

Check the help of the sentence MODIFY (itab):
https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapmodify_itab_single.htm

```
DATA: workarea TYPE your_type.

workarea-field = value.
"modifying for an index
MODIFY your_table INDEX your_index FROM workarea TRANSPORTING field.
"modifying for a condition
MODIFY your_table FROM workarea TRANSPORTING field WHERE your_condition.
```

Or you can use FIELD-SYMBOLS, as has been pointed before me by Anton.

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
TYPES: begin OF ty_itab,
       number1 TYPE n,
END OF ty_itab.

DATA: itab TYPE TABLE OF ty_itab,
      wa_itab like line of itab,
      lv_tabix TYPE sy-tabix.

APPEND wa_itab TO itab.

lv_tabix = sy-tabix.
READ TABLE itab INTO wa_itab INDEX lv_tabix.
wa_itab-number1 = '1'.
MODIFY itab FROM wa_itab INDEX lv_tabix.

BREAK-POINT.
```

[image: debug]